# Entity framework, check duplicates ignoring case

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to check for duplicates in Entity Framework using Linq-To-Entities, ignoring cases. What's the best way to do it? As far as I'm aware, context.[Entity].Contains(item, IEqualityComparer) method is not supported.

Do I have to do ToList() which reads the entire table into memory just to check it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest the best place to look for duplicates is in the belly of the beast - the database. Much easier/faster.

However, if you *must* do it in the code, you could try **[StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase.aspx)**:

```
StringComparer comparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
var caseInsensitiveResults = ctx.SomeObjectSet.Where(x => comparer.Equals(x.Field1, x.Field2));
```

As the **.Equals** method of the **StringComparer** object returns true/false, you can use it as the predicate.

Are you trying to look for duplicates in one table? Define "duplicate" in your specific scenario, might help us help you.

**EDIT**

Since your saying your looking for duplicate rows in a single table, the above won't work. It was just an example.

You'll need to use that comparer code in the GroupBy clause instead.

However, i still think you should do this in the database.

Comment: I am looking for duplicates as in "ABCD" "abcd" in a single table.

Comment: Are you planning on "fixing" them in the code itself, or is this just a report?